# How to change backgound image when hovering over elements with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have to change a background image when hovering over four different elements (one image for each element)

I've tried this:

HTML:

```
<div class="projects">
  <a v-on:mouseover="hover=myimage1" v-on:mouseout="hover=myimage1">
    <router-link to="/project1">Project1</router-link>
  </a>

  <a v-on:mouseover="hover=myimage2" v-on:mouseout="hover=myimage1">
    <router-link to="/project2">Project2</router-link>
  </a>

  <a v-on:mouseover="hover=myimage3" v-on:mouseout="hover=myimage1">
    <router-link to="/project3">Project3</router-link>
  </a>

  <a v-on:mouseover="hover=myimage4" v-on:mouseout="hover=myimage1">
    <router-link to="/project3">Project3</router-link>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="images">
  <div id="img1">
    {{ hover }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
import myimage from '../assets/images/posters/poster1-2.png'
import myimage2 from '../assets/images/front2.png'
import myimage3 from '../assets/images/front3.png'
import myimage4 from '../assets/images/front4.png'
export default {
  name: 'Index',
  data () {
    return {  
      hover: '',        
      myimage1,
      myimage2,
      myimage3,
      myimage4
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem is that it doesn't show the actual images, but strings:

*/static/img/poster1-2.e797348.png*

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows a string because you're just outputting the value of hover (`{{ hover }}`) in the div. If you want to show an image you should use an img tag or the background-image css property.

With VueJS you can bind inline style to a div like this:

```
<div v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + hover + ')' }"
```

[Binding inline Styles - VueJS Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this easily with CSS, just create a class for each image background and put it directly in `<router-link class="..." ...>` (no need for `<router-link>` inside an `<a>` element).

Here's a pure-HTML example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     .btn {
         font-size: 1rem;
         background-color: #fff;
         cursor: pointer;
         padding: 2rem 4rem;
     }

     .btn:hover {
         background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200);
         color: #fff;
     }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="btn">
      Hover Me
    </button>
  </body>

</html>
```